# How do I get the index values of the selected items in a list box?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a c# list box and want to return the selected items position, ex. [0], [1], [2] etc. I do not want the text in that position. I see a lot of code that returns the text, but not the position value. For example, I want to return the value [0] for Zone A, which is the first list item, not the text "Zone A".

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the data stored in a List Box as an array. `Items` are the display values (like "Zone A") and `Indices` is that element's position (zero-based, not one based).

You're most likely using the [`SelectedItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems?view=netframework-4.8) property to get the display values of selected elements.

To get the indices (positions) of those selected elements, use the [`SelectedIndices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices?view=netframework-4.8) property. This gives you (essentially) an integer array of the positions of the elements that are selected.

That means if on your screen you've selected the first, third, and fourth items you would have a resulting array of 0, 2, and 3.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows.Forms:
There is a specific propperty SelectedIndex.
This will equal -1 if nothing is selected. And it has positive value if something is selected.
If you need multiple selection, In Windows forms you have SelectedIndices.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure it out.